# Automapper Map(decimal, currency) to Money

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper, currency

I have:

```
public class Money
{
   public decimal Amount {get;set;}
   public CurrencyCodeType CurrencyCode {get;set;} //this is an enum
}

public class Person //Domain class
{
   public Money Salary {get;set;}
}

public class PersonDb  //Generated from Db
{
   public decimal SalaryAmount {get;set;}
   public string  SalaryCurrencyCode {get;set;}
}
```

The approach of the money its from here:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/embeddedValue.html

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html

I have the next configuration for Autmapper:

```
public class MoneyProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<decimal, Money>().ConvertUsing<MoneyToDecimalTypeConverter>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Money, decimal>().ConvertUsing<DecimalToMoneyTypeConverter>();
    }

    public class DecimalToMoneyTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<Money, decimal>
    {
        public decimal Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return ((Money)context.SourceValue).Amount;
        }
    }

    public class MoneyToDecimalTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<decimal, Money>
    {
        public Money Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return new Money((decimal)context.SourceValue);
        }
    }
}

public class PersonProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        var mapDomainToDb = Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDb>();
        mapDomainToDb.ForMember(db => db.SalaryAmount, options => options.MapFrom(domain => domain.Salary.Amount));
        mapDomainToDb.ForMember(db => db.SalaryCurrencyCode, options => options.MapFrom(domain => domain.Salary.CurrencyCode));

        var mapDbToDomain = Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDb, Person>();
        // ?????
    }
}
```

I dont know how to map the Db to the Domain, how can I create Money object from decimal and string. Please anyone can help me, Im using automapper for first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to do something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDb, Person>()
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => {
        dest.Salary = new Money();
        dest.Salary.Amount = src.SalaryAmount;
        dest.Salary.CurrencyCode = enum.Parse(typeof(CurrencyCodeType), src.SalaryCurrencyCode);
    });
```

EDIT: Sorry I had the wrong order of things. Editted.

Comment: Hi Simon thanks for answer.
In the line .ForMember(x => x.Salary.Amount, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.SalaryAmount))
I get this error:
Expression 'x => Convert(x.Salary.Amount)' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. 
Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead.

Comment: Oh of course. SIlly me. You can use `AfterMap`.. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Updated. There is probably a nicer way to do this but I am not in a position to check right now :/

Comment: Thank you very much, Its nice for me, im starting to using autommaper and this is a self study project. With this solution I already can delete the MoneyProfile class its not used anymore.